# Chrome extension that will allow me to switch between multiple proxy servers?

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome Extension that will allow me to simply, with a click of my mouse, switch between at least three or more chosen proxy servers with ease, without having to always change my system proxy settings from Internet Explorer all the time.

I would prefer one that is easy to use, can do as I have specified and when I move from school to home I can switch between my schools proxy server to another proxy server when I go home as my school laptop requires the use of a proxy server at home too otherwise I can't go on the internet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm/related?hl=en):

- free
- Google Chrome Extension
- requires two clicks to change switch proxy

[image]

Comment: I tried this one out after I saw your answer and it works great thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/downloads.html):

- free
- Google Chrome Extension (originally developed for Firefox, hence the name)
- requires two clicks to change switch proxy

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will try this one out too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ghost Proxy Control will let you assign a different proxy for each tab for maximum control at the tab level, which should meet your needs. And if you use the Sessions setting, it takes zero clicks to launch it. When you open a new Session tab, it uses a pre-set proxy address. It's an add-on for Ghost Browser (disc.: I'm the founder), which is Chromium based. Switching browsers seems drastic for this feature, but it works just like Chrome and you can auto-import your Chrome extensions and settings at installation. There is a video here: [Set a different proxy for each tab](https://ghostbrowser.com/blog/set-different-proxy-for-each-tab/).